# Undefined method `<<' en Ruby

Tags: ruby

se me ha encomendado hacer una versión del juego Monopoly llamada Qytetet. Actualmente cuento con 4 archivos Ruby, 2 de ellos son clases y los otros 2 son módulos (uno de ellos contiene a su vez otra clase). Les explico un poco;

- **Clase Sorpresa**: Tiene 3 atributos de instancia; @texto, @tipo y @valor. Contiene el método initialize y el método to_s.
- **Clase Qytetet**: Tiene el atributo de instancia @mazo. También un método de clase que inicializa @mazo con los elementos correspondientes: una descripción (@texto), un valor (@valor) y un tipo (@tipo).
- **Módulo TipoSorpresa**: Contiene los tipos de sorpresa.
- **Módulo-Clase PruebaQytetet**: Contiene atributo de clase @@juego, 3 métodos de clase para realizar algunas operaciones y el método de clase main, que busca imprimir los resultados de las 3 operaciones (y evidentemente crear un nuevo mazo y demás).

El problema es que al ejecutar en NetBeans, obtengo el siguiente error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass

El error se produce en la línea 15 de qytetet.rb, justo al asignar el primer elemento al array @mazo. Les dejo con los ćodigos correspondientes.

sorpresa.rb

```
    class Sorpresa

  def initialize(nuevo_texto, nuevo_tipo, nuevo_valor)
    @texto = nuevo_texto
    @tipo = nuevo_tipo
    @valor = nuevo_valor
  end

  attr_reader :texto, :tipo, :valor

  def to_s
    puts "Texto: #{@texto} \n Valor: #{@valor} \n Tipo: #{@tipo}"
  end
end
```

qytetet.rb

```
require_relative "tipo_sorpresa"

class Qytetet

  def initialize
    @mazo = Array.new
  end

  attr_reader :mazo

  def self.inicializar_cartas_sorpresa
    @mazo<< Sorpresa.new("Te han pillado saqueando las arcas públicas del estado, vas a la cárcel.", 9, TipoSorpresa::IRACASILLA)
    @mazo<< Sorpresa.new("No sabemos si estabas cerca de la casilla inicial o no, pero ahora lo vas a estar.", 1, TipoSorpresa::IRACASILLA)
    @mazo<< Sorpresa.new("¿Eres supersticioso?", 13, TipoSorpresa::IRACASILLA)
    @mazo<< Sorpresa.new("Resulta que un funcionario de la cárcel es amigo tuyo. De casualidades está hecha la vida. Sales de la cárcel.", 0, TipoSorpresa::SALIRCARCEL)
    @mazo<< Sorpresa.new("Tus rivales te odian tanto que les obligamos a que te den lo que lleven suelto en la cartera.", 200, TipoSorpresa::PORJUGADOR)
    @mazo<< Sorpresa.new("Parece que te está gustando el juego, por eso tendrás que recompensar a tus rivales.", -300, TipoSorpresa::PORJUGADOR)
    @mazo<< Sorpresa.new("¡Enhorabuena! Te ha tocado la lotería, pero la agencia tributaria se va a quedar casi todo.", 250, TipoSorpresa::PAGARCOBRAR)
    @mazo<< Sorpresa.new("Vamos a jugar a algo, tú me das algo de dinero y yo no te doy nada. ¿Qué te parece?", -250, TipoSorpresa::PAGARCOBRAR)
    @mazo<< Sorpresa.new("Vaya, esta sorpresa parece que te va a quitar algo de dinero por los hoteles y casas de tus rivales, siempre y cuando tú estés de acuerdo... o no.", -150, TipoSorpresa::PORCASAHOTEL)
    @mazo<< Sorpresa.new("Estás de suerte. Tus propiedades acaban de evadir impuestos y te dan algo más de dinero extra.", 200, TipoSorpresa::PORCASAHOTEL)
  end
end
```

tipo_sorpresa.rb

```
module TipoSorpresa
    PAGARCOBRAR = :Pagar_cobrar
    IRACASILLA = :Ir_casilla
    PORCASAHOTEL = :Por_casahotel
    PORJUGADOR = :Por_jugador
    SALIRCARCEL = :Salir_carcel
end
```

prueba_qytetet.rb

```
require_relative "sorpresa"
require_relative "qytetet"

module ModeloQytetet
  class PruebaQytetet
    @@juego = Array.new

    def self.mayor_que_cero
      mayor_cero = Array.new
      for s in @@juego.mazo
        if(mazo.valor > 0)
          mayor_cero.mazo = s
        end
      end
      return mayor_cero
    end

    def self.tipo_casilla
      tipo_casilla = Array.new
      for s in @@juego.mazo
        if(mazo.tipo == :Ir_casilla)
          tipo_casilla.mazo = s
        end
      end
      return tipo_casilla
    end

    def self.tipo_sorpresa(sorpresa)
      tipo_sorpresa = Array.new
      for s in TipoSorpresa::constants
        if(mazo.tipo == sorpresa)
          tipo_sorpresa = s
        end
      end
      return tipo_sorpresa
    end

    def self.main
      Qytetet.inicializar_cartas_sorpresa

      PruebaQytetet.mayor_que_cero
      PruebaQytetet.tipo_casilla
      PruebaQytetet.tipo_sorpresa
    end
  end

  PruebaQytetet.main
end
```

Agradecería un poco de ayuda, no entiendo para nada ese error. Creo que tiene que ver con la sintaxis @@mazo<< [...], pero así me han indicado que lo haga. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el método `self.inicializar_cartas_sorpresa` es un método de la *clase*, no de una *instancia* de la clase (i.e. objeto). Al momento de ejecutar `Qytetet.inicializar_cartas_sorpresa` la variable `@mazo` no se ha inicializado (el método `initialize` se ejecuta únicamente al crear un objeto nuevo con `new`), por lo tanto su valor es `nil`, el cual no tiene el método `<<`.

Una opción para corregir ese error es que tu método sea de *instancia*, lo cual logras quitando `self`:

```
class Qytetet
  def initialize
    @mazo = Array.new
  end

  attr_reader :mazo

  def inicializar_cartas_sorpresa
    # ...
  end
end
```

Y, en `PruebaQytetet.main` crea un objeto `Qytetet` y luego llama el método:

```
module ModeloQytetet
  class PruebaQytetet
    # ...

    def self.main
      qytetet = Qytetet.new
      qytetet.initializar_cartas_sorpresa

      PruebaQytetet.mayor_que_cero
      PruebaQytetet.tipo_casilla
      PruebaQytetet.tipo_sorpresa
    end
  end

  PruebaQytetet.main
end
```

---

Aún corrigiendo el error anterior tu código va a fallar ya que veo varios errores, siendo `@@juego = Array.new` el que más destaca; esto te generará error pues después llamas el método `mazo` sobre esta variable la cual, al ser un arreglo, no tiene ese método. Me imagino que lo que buscas es que en `@@juego` tengas el `mazo` generado con la clase `Qytetet`, lo cual puedes lograr de la siguiente manera:

```
module ModeloQytetet
  class PruebaQytetet
    @@juego = Qytetet.new

    # ...

    def self.main
      @@juego = Qytetet.new
      @@juego.inicializar_cartas_sorpresa

      PruebaQytetet.mayor_que_cero
      PruebaQytetet.tipo_casilla
      PruebaQytetet.tipo_sorpresa
    end
  end

  PruebaQytetet.main
end
```

Aún haciendo la corrección sugerida, seguirás teniendo más errores debido a que hay variables (e.g. `mazo`) que no has inicializado pero utilizas, por ejemplo en este fragmento:

```
def self.mayor_que_cero
  mayor_cero = Array.new

  for s in @@juego.mazo
    if(mazo.valor > 0)     # esta línea te generará error (`mazo` no existe)
      mayor_cero.mazo = s  # esta línea te generará error (método `mazo` no existe)
    end
  end
  return mayor_cero
end
```

Para resolver el primer error, te sugiero utilizar el método `each`; para solucionar el segundo puedes crear un nuevo objeto `Qytetet` en lugar de un arreglo en la variable `mayor_cero`; por ejemplo:

```
def self.mayor_que_cero
  mayor_cero = Qytetet.new

  @@juego.mazo.each do |sorpresa|
    if(sorpresa.valor > 0)
      mayor_cero.mazo << sorpresa
    end
  end

  return mayor_cero
end
```

Este fragmento de código no arrojará errores, pero no estoy seguro si respeta la lógica/reglas del juego; este es solo un ejemplo para que puedas ver el tipo de errores que hay en tu código. De hecho deberás modificar más tu código pues, aún aplicando todo lo sugerido aquí, seguirás teniendo más errores.

---

Esta respuesta resolverá el error que muestras en tu pregunta, pero espero también te sirva para darte un poco más de dirección para terminar tu programa.